# Need help to convert below query from My SQL to MS SQL Group_Concat function

Tags: mysql, sql-server, group-concat

I need help to convert below query to MS SQL from my sql

```
SELECT 
            md.ID AS `ID`,  
            t1.Name AS `Name`, 
            group_concat(IF(t2.Column3 = 'Value1',   t1.Value, NULL)) AS `Value1`,
            group_concat(IF(t2.Column3 = 'Value2',   t1.Value, NULL)) AS `Value2`,
            group_concat(IF(t2.Column3 = 'Value3',   t1.Value, NULL)) AS `Value3`
            FROM Table1 t1
            LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.Column1 = t2.Column1
            GROUP BY t1.Id  ;
```

Comment: what is md.ID?  please at least show a query that is working in mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can use `STRING_AGG(expression, ',')` in place of `GROUP_CONCAT(expression)`, as of SQL Server 2017.  For older versions, there seem to be several ways to do it (including installing a GROUP_CONCAT function), none of which I know enough of SQL Server to understand; see [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005) and links in that question.

And you can use `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END` (or also just `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END` if the else result is NULL) in place of `IF(..., ..., ...)`.  CASE is also valid in mysql.

But you will need to group by t1.Name or select something like `MAX(t1.Name)` instead, since you can't use non-aggregate columns that aren't grouped by (just as you can't in modern versions of mysql using modern default settings).

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=2db9d4c13c6c68bcf286bd707bfe144a)

Comment: Thanks for the Answer but I have Sql server 2014 So I will not be able to use String_AGG function.